# Morphia custom converter: Can I insert a nested Java object's fields directly into the parent document?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have the following classes:

```
@Entity(value="students", noClassnameStored=true)
public class Student {
    @Id 
    private String studentId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Address address;
}

public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private Integer zip;
    private String state;
}
```

When I save the instances of the Student class, I want them to be saved in the following format inside the Mongo database:

```
{
 _id: "12345",
 firstName: "Cler",
 lastName: "Fit",
 street: "123 xyz"
 city: "unnt",
 zip: 76443
 state: "IM"
}
```

In other words, even though the Java object being saved has a nested member, I want it to be saved as a flat structure in the resulting document. Can I do that in Morphia? I am aware I can do it by defining a custom converter on the "Student" class. But I have way too many fields in that class than I have shown above, and I don't want to individually handle every one of those. Ideally I want a custom converter defined on the "Address" class which can hopefully accomplish the same result.

Tried searching through the Morphia API documentation. Unfortunately nothing much is mentioned in the API documentation.

Comment: Can you explain why you'd want to lose the nested structure of address? That's sort of the whole point of a document database like Mongo

Comment: Mainly because the consumers who access the data from Mongo datastore prefer it to be flat. Otherwise, many consumers will have to change many different things within their applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Morphia does not currently support flattened documents like that, no.  You might be able to coerce that with the `@Pre`- and `@Post`- annotations to massage data in and out of that shape, but that's a lot of manual mapping.